# Animator on a WorldSpace Canvas

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

Ok, so I have my world space canvas attached to the player object. In my script I have a reference like this :

```
 GameObject myWorldCanvas;

Awake()
{
 myWorldCanvas= transform.FindChild("nameOfObject").gameObject;
}
```

Then when the right conditions are met I simply activate the object like this :

```
myWorldCanvas.SeActive(true);
```

This worked perfectly until I added a animator to the object. If I manually enable/disable the object in the scene the animation works perfectly(it just changes the scale to give it a pop effect), but when the object is activated by my script the animation still plays and changes the scale values but nothing is rendered. In play mode if I manually enable/disable the animation works.

Any ideas ? If you need more info or screens let me know.

Edit : the canvas has some buttons as children and when I mouse over something seems to be refreshed and the images show up on screen.

Edit: Further test have show that manually disabling and enabling the Canvas component also shows the images, but If the canvas and game object are enabled from a script nothing shows up on the screen.

Edit: I solved the problem by disabling the canvas component on the first key of the animation and then enabling it on the second one where the Y scale is set to 0. This seems more like a hack and I dont like it. Does anyone have a idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was the the animation was scaling the canvas from 0 on the xyz axis. Changing the animation to begin the scaling from 0.1 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this problem. It is because Unity's feature of the animation window.

The animation window allows you to record the states of your objects into your animations. This can be turned off by pressing the red circle toggle on the top-left corner of the animation window. But if you forget to do that, it will automatically record your every single action, including activating and deactivating the canvas.

This is quite an annoying feature, but I don't know how to disable. So just remember to close the animation window when you don't use.

Comment: you dont seem to get it. Adding the disable/enable to the animation fixed my issue. The problem is in the canvas itslef

Comment: You meant disabling the animator fixed your issue?

Comment: no I mean disabling and enabling the canvas component in  the first two keys of the animation fixed my issue